# How to specify routing for wwwroot resources in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

How to specify routing for wwwroot resources ? I wrote default routing for my main controller whichs looks like this:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Post}/{action=Index}");
        });
```

It works fine and loads resources from my wwwroot/images directory
[image]

But when Im trying to use another controller it adds controller prefix at the begining like this.
[image]

Comment: By using custom static file middleware.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.